# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Page Load :-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Try
        Page.Title = "Batches - " & Website

        BindBatches()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.WriteError("Error in Page_Load of Batches/batches.aspx", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

This sub-routine binds batch_name in grid view

```
 Protected Sub BindBatches()
    Try
        Dim ds As New DataSet()
        ds = Dal.ExecuteDataset("select batch_name from tblBatch")
        If Not ds Is Nothing AndAlso ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            gvBatches.DataSource = ds
            gvBatches.DataBind()
            gvBatches.Visible = True
        Else
            gvBatches.Visible = False
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.WriteError("Error in BindBatches of Batches/batches.aspx", ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Here is gridview :-

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvBatches" runat="server">
  <Columns>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Batch Name">
          <HeaderStyle Width="40px"></HeaderStyle>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblBatchName" runat="server">
                    </asp:Label>
               </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And databound event :-

```
Protected Sub gvBatches_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBatches.RowDataBound
  If e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
    Dim batchName As Label = e.Row.FindControl("lblBatchName")
    batchName.Text = e.Row.DataItem("batch_name")
  End If
End Sub
```

But when i debug it will show below exception on - gvBatches.DataBind()

```
DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'id'.
```

I don't understand what is this id ? There is no such column in my table.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first set `OPTION STRICT` to on. It even hurts to see this code(`DataItem` is an `Object`):

```
batchName.Text = e.Row.DataItem("batch_name")
```

Instead try to cast it appropriately:

```
Dim row As DataRow = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView).Row
batchName.Text = row.Field(Of String)("batch_name")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your aspx file you can change you label declaration to

```
<asp:Label ID="lblBatchName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("batch_name") %>'>
```

and you don't need `Protected Sub gvBatches_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvBatches.RowDataBound` function

Comment: i did that ..but still it asks for id

Comment: could you please give the Page_Load() and page_Init() funtion definations?

Comment: ok i found the solution when i added If e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Row.RowType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem block .it disappears..thanks